# Trigger based on AUTO_INCREMENT field works incorrectly on multiple row INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-insert, auto-increment

I use MySQL 5.6 with an `item` table (InnoDB) as given below.

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| item_id | int(11) |
| item_code | varchar(20) |
| name | varchar(100) |
| cat_type | varchar(50) |
| prod_grp | varchar(12) |
| stock | int(11) |
| price | double |
| date_added | timestamp |

The `item_id` column is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field.

There are two other tables called `products` & `category`.
`products` table has `prod_grp` and `prod_code` columns.
`category` table has `cat_type` and `cat_code` columns.

`item_code` of `item` table is a derived by concatenating `item_id`, `cat_code` and `prod_code` columns of the `item`, `category` and `products` table respectively.

I have a trigger defined as below for the `item` table, which can auto update the `item_code` when there's an `INSERT` into `item` table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `add_item_code` 
  BEFORE INSERT ON `item`
   FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
    IF (NEW.item_code IS NULL OR NEW.item_code = '' ) THEN
       SET NEW.item_code = ( 
            SELECT CONCAT("MM-", cat_code, "-", prod_code, "-", id.item_id)
            FROM products, category, 
                (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT AS item_id
                FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'comdb'
                AND TABLE_NAME = 'item') AS id
            WHERE products.prod_grp = NEW.prod_grp
              AND category.cat_type = NEW.cat_type
       );
    END IF;
   END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I do an insert as below, the trigger works and updates the item_code as expected.

```
INSERT INTO `item`
(`prod_grp`, `name`, `stock`, `price`, `cat_type`)
VALUES ('h & k','Crooks mirror','10','333.5','home')
```

Say, if the last `item_id` is 723, then the `item_code` is updated as "MM-hm-hk-724", as 724 is the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

However, when I do an insert with multiple values, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value becomes the latest one, which results in incorrect `item_code`.

```
INSERT INTO `item`
(`prod_grp`, `name`, `stock`, `price`, `cat_type`)
VALUES ('h & k','Crooks mirror','10','333.5','home'), 
('DIY','Screw Driver','14','10.5','tools'), 
('h & k','bulb','120','21.5','electricals');
```

Say, if the last `item_id` is 723, then the `item_code` is updated for these three items as below

| item_id | item_code |
| --- | --- |
| 724 | MM-hm-hk-724 |
| 725 | MM-tl-dy-727 |
| 726 | MM-el-hk-727 |

As you can notice the last two item_codes are updated with a wrong item_id.
I simply do not understand what is happening. Can somebody help to fix this issue?

Comment: Noway. Of course, you may use the technique which uses additional `id` generation service table, but... the value for `item_code` is completely derived from another values, so its storing is excess - you can easily build it in retrieving query when its value needed.

Comment: *I simply do not understand what is happening.* First value (724) is taken before the request for AI values generation (i.e. this value was stored in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES before query execution). After trigger fires for 1st row before saving the value into the table the request for AI values generation performed, needed amount of values (3) generated, and new AI value is saved into INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, so all the next trigger firings retrieves this incorrect value.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the explanation. It fits. However its not at all intuitive for a trigger to work with "FOR EACH ROW" statement. The understanding is for each INSERT, the trigger has to work and for each insert the increment has to happen. But probably MySQL thinks AUTO_INCREMENT can happen as one update after all bulk inserts, instead of an update for each inserted row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick - you may try to use user-defined variable.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `add_item_code` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `item`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.item_code IS NULL OR NEW.item_code = '' ) THEN
        IF @add_item_code_autoincrement IS NULL THEN
            SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
            INTO @add_item_code_autoincrement
            FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'item';
        END IF;
        SET NEW.item_code = CONCAT("MM-", @add_item_code_autoincrement);
        SET @add_item_code_autoincrement = @add_item_code_autoincrement + 1;
    END IF;
END;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=97a725cd6a3850d52e6548ac1f09778c

This is a sample only, so retrieving the values from another tables is removed. The variable name must be long and complex for to avoid any interference.

**Caution!** This code is absolutely non-safe in concurrent insertions. If concurrent inserts performed then this code will produce wrong values with high probability. Also it will give wrong result if you use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Moreover, this code may give incorrect result even under the most favorable conditions. So, if you decide to use this trick nevertheless, create service event procedure which will check generated values correctness and correct them if they're incorrectly generated. For example, it can be executed each minute and check the rows which are not more than 2 minutes old.

---

> additional table will be an overkill. But I am curious to know the solution. – Die-Bugger

Schematically:

```
CREATE additional_table (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) 
    AUTO_INCREMENT = {current AUTO_INCREMENT value for `item` table} ;

CREATE TRIGGER `add_item_code` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `item`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO additional_table VALUES (DEFAULT);
    SET @add_item_code_autoincrement := LAST_INSERT_ID();
--  DELETE FROM additional_table WHERE id < @add_item_code_autoincrement;
    IF (NEW.item_code IS NULL OR NEW.item_code = '' ) THEN
        SET NEW.item_code = CONCAT("MM-", @add_item_code_autoincrement);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: As you had clearly stated, this is risky. There will be certainly concurrent inserts. Hence cannot use this as a solution. Have to think of an alternate.

Comment: @Die-Bugger Alternative, concurrent-safe solution uses trigger and additional table. Do you need in such option?

Comment: additional table will be an overkill. But I am curious to know the solution.

Comment: @Die-Bugger Added.